# Distinct list by specified fields and ignoring other but return them too

Tags: c#, linq

I have a my collection class of items with fields.

```
class Item
{
    string s1;
    string s2;
    string s3;
    string d1;
    string d2;
}
```

MyCollection looks like that:

```
    public class  MyCollection : ICollection<Item>, IEnumerable
{}
```

I need to distinct that list by 's1', 's2', 's3' but in return get list with all these fields (s1, s2, s3, d1, d2), without duplicated items. So in other words, In return I need a `MyCollection<Item>`, not `List<anonymousType>`

For now I have something like

`var list = source.Select(k => new { k.s1, k.s2, k.s2 }).Distinct().ToList();`

but it returns a list with only s1,s2,s3 fields.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Which `d1` and `d2` do you want when you have multiple values of them for a given `s1, s2, s3`? You can start with a `GroupBy` instead of a distinct, then you can `Select(x => new Item{s1=x.s1, ...}`, there are several options but you need to know what to select for `d1, d2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a IEqualityComparer<> and use that.

```
class ItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;

        return x.s1 == y.s1 && x.s2 == y.s2 && x.s3 == y.s3;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item obj)
    {
        var hashCode = obj.s1.GetHashCode();
        hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ obj.s2.GetHashCode();
        hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ obj.s3.GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Then you can do this

```
var distinctList = list.Distinct(new ItemComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you please explain your GetHashCode method implementation?

Comment: hashcode should be unique. That there is basically joining the hashes of the three strings into something that should be quite unique.